# Alternative of -webkit-outer-spin-button and -webkit-inner-spin-button in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, input

I need some space to the left of the up & down arrows in my input number field, where I plan to put some symbols by default. But `-webkit-outer-spin-button` and `-webkit-inner-spin-button`  doesn't work on Firefox now. Is there any alternative which Firefox supports? I need to right-align the text and the text (here number) must show up to the left of the default symbols.

What I try to achieve is something like this (in Chrome):
https://jsfiddle.net/1dddncj0/3/

But this trick is not working in Firefox or Edge.

Comment: You may need to use Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: I have no problem using javascript. But how to achieve this? @GabrielCheung

Comment: Do you need the spin-button on Firefox?

Comment: Yes. @GabrielCheung

Comment: I misunderstood your requirement. Seems that JS could not meet your requirement. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure it works well. And not suggesting you to achieve this requirement. I think you should get rid of the default spin-button.

HTML:

```
<div class="edit-wrapper">
  <input id="edit_input_1" type="number" min="0" max="999">
  <input id="edit_input_2" type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.edit-wrapper {
  max-width: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.edit-wrapper input[type=number] {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
}

.edit-wrapper input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.edit-wrapper input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.edit-wrapper input[type=number]::-moz-outer-spin-button,
.edit-wrapper input[type=number]::-moz-inner-spin-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.edit-wrapper:before {
    content: '%';
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 1px;
}
#edit_input_1 {
  color: transparent;
  text-align: left;
}
#edit_input_2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding-right: 33px;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var viewInput = document.getElementById('edit_input_2');
var manipulateInput = document.getElementById('edit_input_1');

manipulateInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
    viewInput.value = manipulateInput.value;
})

manipulateInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    viewInput.value = manipulateInput.value;
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dddncj0/5/

Comment: It is not that much responsive. In chrome, it is preventing me from entering something using keyboard.

Comment: No, it's not a good solution. That's why I suggest you to get rid of the default spin button and write a component yourself. I also tried `direction: rtl` with `text-algin: left;` and `text-intent: 30px`, still got no luck on Firefox.

Comment: Writing a component myself doesn't seem easy for a newbie like me @gabriel

Comment: Quite similar with this solution, just to create a spin button with Javascript listening the click event, and update the input value.

Answer (score -1):

See [How TO - Hide Arrows From Input Number](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp). The relevant part:

```
/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```