# input type arrow spin-button non-standard

Tags: html, css

I am looking at [MDN for spinners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-outer-spin-button) (arrows for input `type="number"`) and it says it is non standard. The way I remember is MDN also tell you what to use but in this case, it isn't. 
My problem is that while I am using

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  margin: 0;
}
```

It works for chrome but not for firefox. So I am guessing due to non-standard it is not applying, What is the "Standard" Workaround for it?

Comment: `-moz-` vendor prefix in `-webkit-` selector!!  it's invalid I guess

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777047/alternative-of-webkit-outer-spin-button-and-webkit-inner-spin-button-in-firefo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Spinner in Input Number - Firefox 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372903/hide-spinner-in-input-number-firefox-29)

Answer (score 1):

`input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button` this will work as a selector when browser is `webkit` otherwise none of styles within this selector will be applied.

```css
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```